# How to solve $x^2-(a+1)x+2a-2=0$ for every parameter $a$ from $\mathbb R$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, parametric, parametrization

I need to solve this equation. It says which number $x$ is the solution to this equation for every parameter $a$? I know how to solve parametric equation, however, i don't know which condition i should use here? I tried to find a single number x so i solved $x_1=x_2$ but the solution is not every $a$ from $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

Discriminant:

$$\Delta=(a+1)^2-4(2a-2)=a^2-6a+9=(a-3)^2$$

and your solution is, with the quadratic formula

$$x_{1,2}=\frac{(a+1)\pm(a-3)}2$$

Finish now the argument.

Answer (score 1):

using the formula for a quadratic equation we get
$$x_{1,2}=\frac{a+1}{2}\pm\sqrt{(\frac{a+1}{2})^2-2a+2}$$
simplifying this we get $$x_1=2$$ or $$x_2=a-1$$

Answer (score 0):

If you solve the equation you get that $x_1=a-1$ and $x_2=2$. Thus, independently from the value of $a$, $2$ is the solution of this equation.

Comment: Edited, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting $-(a+1)x$ using the factors of $2(a-1)$:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
x^2-(a+1)x+2(a-1)&=0
\\\Rightarrow x^2-2x-(a-1)x+2(a-1)&=0
\\ \Rightarrow x(x-2)-(a-1)(x-2)&=0
\\ \Rightarrow (x-2)(x-(a-1))&=0.
\end{eqnarray}$$

Using no-zero-divisors:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
 \Rightarrow x-2=0&\text{ or }&x-(a-1)=0
\\ \Rightarrow x=2&\text{ or }&x=a-1,
\end{eqnarray}$$

so that $x=2$ is the answer to the question that you asked.